# Redis Graph Bulk Loader Issue

Tags: redis

I have created redis cloud subscription and followed the instructions as mentioned in this document https://github.com/RedisGraph/redisgraph-bulk-loader. I am seeing error when I followed the instructions. I have also tried to use example2 csv but received the same error. Error : "Python int too large to convert to C long"
[image]

```
redisgraph-bulk-insert GRAPH_DEMO -n example/Person.csv -n example/Country.csv -r example/KNOWS.csv -r example/VISITED.csv
-h ***** -p ***** -a ********
```

Answer (score 0):

I also received this message while trying to insert csv data (all data was quoted to be imported as string) into a graph. So what I did was to simply comment this line `csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)` in entity_file.py. It worked in my case, but I don’t think this would be safe for every use case.